# Why is fs::read_dir() thread safe on POSIX platforms

Tags: multithreading, rust, directory, posix, readdir

###### Some Background

Originally, Rust [switched from `readdir(3)` to `readdir_r(3)`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/12692) for thread safety. But `readdir_r(3)` [has some problems](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/86649), then they changed it back:

- Linux and Android: [fs: Use readdir() instead of readdir_r() on Linux and Android](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/92778)
- Fuchsia: [Switch Fuchsia to readdir (instead of readdir_r)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/40024)
- ...

So, in the current implementation, [they use `readdir(3)` on most POSIX platforms](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/8f2c56aec7e78165033305811b957fc07b5baa4a/library/std/src/sys/unix/fs.rs#L557-L655)

```rust
#[cfg(any(
    target_os = "android",
    target_os = "linux",
    target_os = "solaris",
    target_os = "fuchsia",
    target_os = "redox",
    target_os = "illumos"
))]
fn next(&mut self) -> Option<io::Result<DirEntry>> {
unsafe {
    loop {
    // As of POSIX.1-2017, readdir() is not required to be thread safe; only
    // readdir_r() is. However, readdir_r() cannot correctly handle platforms
    // with unlimited or variable NAME_MAX.  Many modern platforms guarantee
    // thread safety for readdir() as long an individual DIR* is not accessed
    // concurrently, which is sufficient for Rust.
    super::os::set_errno(0);
    let entry_ptr = readdir64(self.inner.dirp.0);
```

###### Thread issue of `readdir(3)`

The problem of `readdir(3)` is that its return value (`struct dirent *`) is a pointer pointing to the internal buffer of the directory stream (`DIR`), thus can be overwritten by the following `readdir(3)` calls. So if we have a `DIR` stream, and share it with multiple threads, with all threads calling `readdir(3)`, which is a race condition.

If we want to safely handle this, an *external synchronization* is needed.

###### My question

Then I am curious about what Rust did to avoid such issues. Well, it seems that they just call `readdir(3)`, `memcpy` the return value to their caller-allocated buffer, and then return. But this function is not marked as `unsafe`, this makes me confused.

So my question is why is it safe to call `fs::read_dir()` in multi-threaded programs?

There is a [comment](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/34668#issue-163903843) stating that it is safe to use it in Rust without extra external synchronization, but I didn't get it...

> It requires external synchronization if a particular directory stream may be shared among threads, but I believe we avoid that naturally from the lack of `&mut` aliasing. `Dir` is `Sync`, but only `ReadDir` accesses it, and only from its mutable `Iterator` implementation.

---

## OP's edit after 3 months

At the time of writing this question, I was not familiar with multi-threaded programming in Rust. After refining my skill, taking another look at this post makes me realize that it is pretty easy to verify this question:

```rust
// With scpped threads
// Does not compile since we can not mutably borrow pwd more than once
use std::{
    fs::read_dir,
    thread::{scope, spawn},
};

fn main() {
    let mut pwd = read_dir(".").unwrap();

    scope(|s| {
        for _ in 1..10 {
            s.spawn(|| {
                let entry = pwd.next().unwrap().unwrap();
                println!("{:?}", entry.file_name());
            });
        }
    })
}
```

```rust
// Use interior mutability to share it with multiple threads
// This code does compile because synchronization is applied (RwLock)
use std::{
    fs::read_dir,
    sync::{Arc, RwLock},
    thread::spawn,
};

fn main() {
    let pwd = Arc::new(RwLock::new(read_dir(".").unwrap()));

    for _ in 1..10 {
        spawn({
            let pwd = Arc::clone(&pwd);
            move || {
                let entry = pwd.write().unwrap().next().unwrap().unwrap();
                println!("{:?}", entry.file_name());
            }
        }).join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`readdir` is not safe when called from multiple threads *with the same `DIR* dirp` parameter* (i.e. with the same `self.inner.dirp.0` in the Rust case) but it may be called safely with different `dirp`s. Since calling `ReadDir::next` requires a `&mut self`, it is guaranteed that nobody else can call it from another thread at the same time on the same `ReadDir` instance, and so it is safe.

Comment: God, I totally forgot about this, exclusive reference! Thanks!